# Intellisense in custom xml file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd

I have created a custom xml file which I use as a config for my application. I'm reading it by my own (I have some reasons not to use app.config or any other standart file)

I'm using it for my framework, so user who will change this config file, will use Visual Studio for editing. I want to add Intellisense, to support this config file.

I have found many solutions, but all of them are designed so my .xsd for this config file should be copied to Schema folder in VS. But I need to store it in the same folder as my .xml file. Actually I can't copy or change anything in VS folder - it should be standalone.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my question by myself.
I need to set targetNamespace to the root of my xml, and place xsd beside with the same targetNamespace.

Don't know why it was so hard to find this information, the answer is very simple

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to achieve same thing. Can you please show an example of xml and xsd you're using?

Comment: But the main point is to set targetNamespace in xsd equal to xmlns in config.xml